# Why does pow works here

Tags: c, function, integer, double, pow

From what i know the function pow works only with double and returns double
but in this programm everything works fine and its all in int.
i just want to understand like so why even though it only works with double here it works with ints

```
void squre_OF_3_digit_number()
{
    int num;//123
    do
    {
        printf("please enter a 3 digit number--> ");
        scanf_s("%d",&num);
    } while (num>999 || num<100);
    int n0 = pow((num%10),2);
    int n1 = pow(((num%100)/10),2);
    int n2 = pow((num/100),2);
    printf(" %d+%d+%d=%d ",n0,n1,n2,n0+n1+n2);
    
}`
```

Comment: Note: multiply number by itself is also a method to get it squared.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go through this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-typecasting/

Here, the compiler has automatically converted (called implicit conversion) the `int` type data to `double` type data.

Comment: So what happens? to n0,n1,n2 that gets the value do they automatically become double also?

Comment: @arturanikin No, `pow` result is converted to `int` by discarding fractional part.

Comment: @arturanikin Beware that although typecasting from higher datatype to lower types (eg. float to int or double to float, etc) is done implicitly, it may result in unintentional data loss. In the case of n0, n1, n2, the `pow` function is returning a `double` value, but as the lvalue (in this case, the variables n0, n1, n2) are of `int`, therefore only integer part is assigned to n0, n1, n2. Compilers may warn you if there's such casting. If you really need such type of typecasting, you can explicitly typecast them, then the compiler doesn't throw warning.

Comment: This is not casting or typecasting. As the page you link to says, typecasting is converting a value to another type **using a cast operator**. A cast operator is a type name in parentheses, like `(int)`. The code in the question has no casts. It only has implicit conversions. There is no such thing as an implicit typecast; a cast is an explicit operator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is there a differemce between casting and typecasting?

Comment: @Cinverse: Some people use “typecast” to mean “cast.” The C standard uses only “cast,” not “typecast.” Conversions without a cast are simply conversions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If there's any risky implicit conversion then the compiler throws "implicit conversion" warning, right? So is the "cast" operator used to either prevent compiler from throwing "implicit conversion" warning OR to do conversion of the data to datatype other than what compiler would do "Implicitly"?

Comment: Re “If there's any risky implicit conversion the compiler throws "implicit conversion" warning right?”: Some compilers warn of some risky conversions with some command-line switches. Re “So is the "cast" operator used to either prevent compiler from throwing "implicit conversion" warning OR to do conversion of the data to datatype other than what compiler would do "Implicitly"?”: Yes.